# How do I plot Y-axis on right and start time from right and plot a layout in Line chart in MP Chart Android library

Tags: android, graph, mpandroidchart, linechart

I am working on a project where I need to plot data on the line chart, I am using MP chart Android as the library, I need the Y-Axis to start from the right corner and then scroll must be towards left. Also, the current time should be plotted as the first point on X-Axis.

```
 chart.axisLeft.isEnabled = false
 chart.axisRight.isEnabled = true
```

This makes the right Axis enabled but doesn't start the value from right.

The other point is I need to plot a layout on the graph whenever a data is plotted but I am only able to plot Drawables on it, please help me out here.

Comment: Can anyone help here?

Comment: Still waiting for a response here!